# getting an error in fetching solidworks model info

Tags: vb.net, solidworks

Actually I am trying to connect to solidworks through visual studio 2013.I am getting an error stating:" A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WindowsApplication1.exe / Object reference not set to an instance of an object" . Showing Documents as nothing because of which getting error in line "For Each Doc As ModelDoc2 In Documents".

```
Public Sub New()
    SwApp = New SldWorks.SldWorks

    Dim Documents As Object = SwApp.GetDocuments()

    For Each Doc As ModelDoc2 In Documents

        _observableModeldoc.Add(New Modeldocs(Doc.GetPathName, _SwApp))

    Next

End Sub
```

Can anyone please suggest any solution..?

Comment: Based on [this](http://help.solidworks.com/2012/English/api/sldworksapi/Get_Paths_of_Open_Documents_Example_CSharp.htm), one should have Solidworks open with 1 document, for the code to work. Have you the app open?

Comment: Yes I have opened a model doc file in solidworks

Comment: What does `SwApp.GetDocuments().Count` return? Please note that I havent worked on Solidworks.

Comment: Actually by Dim Documents As Object = SwApp.GetDocuments(), we get document currently opened in solidworks. But I m getting value of Documents as nothing though i have document opened in solidworks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this post](https://www.linkedin.com/groups/Create-simple-SolidWorks-StandAlone-Application-4961405.S.235214502) from Artem Taturevich. If you write a standalone app (opposed to SW add-in or macro), then instead of

```
    SwApp = New SldWorks.SldWorks
```

you should use either of GetObject/CreateObject/Activator::CreateInstance functions

Comment: Used SwApp = GetObject(, "SldWorks.Application") instead of SwApp = New SldWorks.SldWorks.. Showing Error Stating : Unhandled exception of type Sysetm.Exception occured and Cannot create activeX component in line "Dim Documents As Object = SwApp.GetDocuments()"

Comment: Actually error is coming the line "Dim Documents As Object = SwApp.GetDocuments()" itself. Error is: Cannot create an activeX component